# How to apply Windows 8 theme via batch file?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, batch, windows-registry, themes

High contrast Windows 8 themes files are found at **\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\**. I want to be able to switch between *hcblack.theme* and *hcwhite.theme* using a batch file. How does one apply Windows 8 theme files via a batch file? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using ThemeSwitcher.exe designed to work from the command prompt, instead I run it from a shortcut. I just click on the icon and it switches to themes, claims to work with win8 also.
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-a-windows-theme-from-the-command-prompt/
I do not know if any addware has since been added to the installer, but it was clean the first time.

This is what the contents of my shortcut would look like
`C:\Desk\batch\ThemeSwitcher.exe C:\Users\Me2Know\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\PsycoRuby.theme`

Quoted if there were spaces in the file names or paths.
 `"C:\wherever you put it\ThemeSwitcher.exe" "C:\Users\Me2Know\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Psyco Ruby.theme"`

If somehow you could not locate the EOA themes it is simple enough to save one out as "custom" even if there are no changes.
This has nothing to do with 3rd party themes or hacking the dll to allow them, and changes that are beyond a simple theme files like Icon replacement. This simple changer has limitations, but works fine with the MS own themes.

Of course you could use proper User %path% stuff  , but I myself always use direct paths for pure speed.